# ERROR: Unexpected EOF while parsing - what is it in Python?

Tags: python

What I'm doing wrong here? I'm beginner in python, so wanna to use modulo

```
import math 
x = int(input("Type number x: "))
y = int(input("Type number for y:")) 
print(math.fmod(x % y))
```

And next one:

```
def modulo(x, y):                        
    return math.fmod(x ,y)
```

During using this code, I'm getting error like this:

```
>    print(math.fmod(x % y)) <br>
TypeError: fmod expected 2 arguments, got 1
```

Comment: `print(math.fmod(x % y))`

Comment: the error tells you to put two arguments in the fmod function, you're entering just one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change the input of your math.fmod() function:

```
import math 
x = int(input("Type number x: "))
y = int(input("Type number for y:")) 
print(math.fmod(x, y))
```

Comment: thanx, it works !  How about with next one? def modulo(x, y):                        
    return math.fmod(x ,y) I've changed to: def modulo(x, y):                        
    return math.fmod(float(x),float(y))  but still not  working

Comment: Error: Modulo function is not working for: x=5, y=32

Comment: Could you print the EXACT error the interpreter is giving you?
That codes works just fine on my computer (with x=5 and y=32),